# Why do mojo or pojo need to be downloaded first and read after it?

Tags: java, h2o

Why do mojo or pojo need to be downloaded first and read after it? Why can't I just use it as an intermediate variable in Java?
I searched the examples and I found that all the examples are like this:

```
h2o.down_load(modelName);

URL mojoURL = MojoUtil.class.getResource(modelName);
 MojoReaderBackend reader = MojoReaderBackendFactory.createReaderBackend(mojoURL, MojoReaderBackendFactory.CachingStrategy.MEMORY);
 MojoModel model = ModelMojoReader.readFrom(reader);
```

Can I use some method like this:

```
String modelName = h2o.train_drf(param).getModelName();
MojoModel model = h2o.getMojoModel(modelName);
```

Furthermore, in document http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/save-and-load-model.html, there are only mentioned R and python of how to download mojo model: saving an H2O binary model with h2o.saveModel (R), h2o.save_model (Python).

How can I do it in java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why is the API done as two function calls?**

I doubt there is a reason; just no-one particularly needed to reduce those two lines to one. (Or, maybe, whoever wrote them always envisaged having to specify the arguments.)

If you are always going to call those two functions in that way, and especially if it happens in more than one place in your code, it definitely makes sense to write the wrapper function you describe.

**Why is there a download involved at all?**

Remember that, even when using a Java client, H2O is running as two processes: the client and the server. So, even when the server part is running on localhost, they are still completely separate, with no shared memory.

**Why is it a zip file**

If you look inside a mojo file, you see lots of little binary files. That would be why it is a zip file: a simple container that can be easily moved around.

Comment: So I always have to download mojo as a zip file using h2o.down_load(modelName) and read the zip file to get mojo model? why zip file is used as intermediate variable?

Comment: That helps a lot. ps： my code is copied from h2o examples using R or Python, but I didn't find how to download mojo as zip in java. There is no method called h2o.download(**) or other similiar name.